# .py file works, converted .exe file doesn't

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, py2exe

EDIT: Turns out the actual error was with the font code - Apparently I had to use

```
pygame.font.SysFont("some_font", font_size)
```

instead of

```
pygame.font.Font(None, font_size)
```

everywhere in my original piece of code.

Consider this question resolved.

I've made a game with pygame and want it to run on computers without Python and Pygame, for which matter I got py2exe and shamelessly copied the pygame2exe code found [here](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe), adjusting it for my file's name and that kind of stuff...

The conversion (I tried both the windows cmd thingy and actual Python, both with the same results) was successful, and when I run the executable file I get a black window without the actual background, the only thing I saw that it worked were the icon and title of the window which were integrated in the Python code. Afterwards I immediately get this error message:

> Runtime error! This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Since the icon was displayed at the top left of the window (which it also has to load an image for) and the background didn't appear, the error was most likely somewhere in between the following few lines, if it's due to some problem in the actual code (although it works in IDLE). There I do the following things:

- Defining variables for images, then defining another variable as that variable so it's a copy of it, so the game works faster
- Loading sound effects and setting their volume
- Setting background music, it's volume and making it on loop

Following that, these are the lines of code up until the setting of the background image.

```
running = True
game = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 150
name = ""
while running==True:
    screen.fill(0)
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for x in range(width/background.get_width()+1):
        for y in range(height/background.get_height()+1):
            screen.blit(background,(x*200,y*200))
```

For reference, this is the code of setup.py (although I doubt that's the problem anyway:

```
try:
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe, pygame
    from modulefinder import Module
    import glob, fnmatch
    import sys, os, shutil
    import operator
except ImportError, message:
    raise SystemExit,  "Unable to load module. %s" % message

#hack which fixes the pygame mixer and pygame font
origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL # save the orginal before we edit it
def isSystemDLL(pathname):
    # checks if the freetype and ogg dll files are being included
    if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ("libfreetype-6.dll", "libogg- 0.dll","sdl_ttf.dll"): # "sdl_ttf.dll" added by arit.
            return 0
    return origIsSystemDLL(pathname) # return the orginal function
py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL = isSystemDLL # override the default function with this one

class pygame2exe(py2exe.build_exe.py2exe): #This hack make sure that pygame default font is copied: no need to modify code for specifying default font
    def copy_extensions(self, extensions):
        #Get pygame default font
        pygamedir = os.path.split(pygame.base.__file__)[0]
        pygame_default_font = os.path.join(pygamedir, pygame.font.get_default_font())

        #Add font to list of extension to be copied
        extensions.append(Module("pygame.font", pygame_default_font))
        py2exe.build_exe.py2exe.copy_extensions(self, extensions)

class BuildExe:
    def __init__(self):
        #Name of starting .py
        self.script = "test.py"

        #Name of program
        self.project_name = "test"

        #Project url
        self.project_url = "about:none"

        #Version of program
        self.project_version = "0.9"

        #License of the program
        self.license = "No license"

        #Auhor of program
        self.author_name = "Me"
        self.author_email = "example@example.com"
        self.copyright = "Copyright (c) 2009 Me."

        #Description
        self.project_description = "Test"

        #Icon file (None will use pygame default icon)
        self.icon_file = None

        #Extra files/dirs copied to game
        self.extra_datas = ["spiel"]

        #Extra/excludes python modules
        self.extra_modules = []
        self.exclude_modules = []

        #DLL Excludes
        self.exclude_dll = ['']
        #python scripts (strings) to be included, seperated by a comma
        self.extra_scripts = []

        #Zip file name (None will bundle files in exe instead of zip file)
        self.zipfile_name = None

        #Dist directory
        self.dist_dir ='dist'

    ## Code from DistUtils tutorial at http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial
    ## Originally borrowed from wxPython's setup and config files
    def opj(self, *args):
        path = os.path.join(*args)
        return os.path.normpath(path)

    def find_data_files(self, srcdir, *wildcards, **kw):
        # get a list of all files under the srcdir matching wildcards,
        # returned in a format to be used for install_data
        def walk_helper(arg, dirname, files):
            if '.svn' in dirname:
                return
            names = []
            lst, wildcards = arg
            for wc in wildcards:
                wc_name = self.opj(dirname, wc)
                for f in files:
                    filename = self.opj(dirname, f)

                    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, wc_name) and not os.path.isdir(filename):
                        names.append(filename)
            if names:
                lst.append( (dirname, names ) )

        file_list = []
        recursive = kw.get('recursive', True)
        if recursive:
            os.path.walk(srcdir, walk_helper, (file_list, wildcards))
        else:
            walk_helper((file_list, wildcards),
                        srcdir,
                        [os.path.basename(f) for f in glob.glob(self.opj(srcdir, '*'))])
        return file_list

    def run(self):
        if os.path.isdir(self.dist_dir): #Erase previous destination dir
            shutil.rmtree(self.dist_dir)

        #Use the default pygame icon, if none given
        if self.icon_file == None:
            path = os.path.split(pygame.__file__)[0]
            self.icon_file = os.path.join(path, 'pygame.ico')

        #List all data files to add
        extra_datas = []
        for data in self.extra_datas:
            if os.path.isdir(data):
                extra_datas.extend(self.find_data_files(data, '*'))
            else:
                extra_datas.append(('.', [data]))

        setup(
            cmdclass = {'py2exe': pygame2exe},
            version = self.project_version,
            description = self.project_description,
            name = self.project_name,
            url = self.project_url,
            author = self.author_name,
            author_email = self.author_email,
            license = self.license,

            # targets to build
            windows = [{
                'script': self.script,
                'icon_resources': [(0, self.icon_file)],
                'copyright': self.copyright
            }],
            options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 2, 'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, \
                                  'excludes': self.exclude_modules, 'packages': self.extra_modules, \
                                  'dll_excludes': self.exclude_dll,
                                  'includes': self.extra_scripts} },
            zipfile = self.zipfile_name,
            data_files = extra_datas,
            dist_dir = self.dist_dir
            )

            if os.path.isdir('build'): #Clean up build dir
            shutil.rmtree('build')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if operator.lt(len(sys.argv), 2):
        sys.argv.append('py2exe')
    BuildExe().run() #Run generation
    raw_input("Press any key to continue") #Pause to let user see that things ends
```

Further information:

- OS: Windows 7, 32 bit
- Pygame version: 1.9.2. (I think - it's the latest version)
- Python version: 2.7.6.
- Py2exe version: Whatever the latest one was
- I never actually had a msvcr90.dll file ***version 9.0.21022.8***, like the py2exe tutorial specifically recommends to use. I now have msvcr71.dll, msvcr100.dll, msvcr100_clr0400.dll and msvcr110_clr0400.dll (intended for this OS) instead, which was what seemed to be available from microsoft packages. Is it possible that represents the problem? If so, where the hell can I get the correct file from? I tried looking it up, but there didn't seem to be any download link for it (at least not that it gives me the exact file I want now).

And if not, do you know where else the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

`msvcr90.dll` comes along with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 runtimes. Grab the version for your architecture, install and try again. [Here is the x86 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=29) and [here is the x64 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336).

Comment: I've tried getting the x86 version, running it, then I selected "Repair" instead of "Uninstall" and that doesn't help it. Should I uninstall it first? (Please assure me it's wise if I do have to do so.)

Comment: Never mind actually, this is a problem solved now, and it was something I would have never come up with on my own. Sorry for taking your time.